# using @cache_response() decorator from drf extensions while using @api_view function view

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I want to cache my API responses. I am using `Django Rest Framework` and want use for this purpose `@cache_response()` decorator from `drf extensions`.

I am following examples from: http://chibisov.github.io/drf-extensions/docs/#cache-response There are only examples of class based views.

When I apply it like this:

```
@api_view(http_method_names=['GET'])
@cache_response()
def my_view(request, some_arg):
    (...)
```

I end up with error:

```
inner() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

Full traceback:

```
Traceback:

    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/core/handlers/base.py" in get_response
      112.                     response = wrapped_callback(request, *callback_args, **callback_kwargs)
    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/decorators/csrf.py" in wrapped_view
      57.         return view_func(*args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/django/views/generic/base.py" in view
      69.             return self.dispatch(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      407.             response = self.handle_exception(exc)
    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/views.py" in dispatch
      404.             response = handler(request, *args, **kwargs)
    File "/Users/andi/.virtualenvs/adfoo/lib/python2.7/site-packages/rest_framework/decorators.py" in handler
      51.             return func(*args, **kwargs)

    Exception Type: TypeError at /api/foo/1/exhibitors/
    Exception Value: inner() takes at least 2 arguments (1 given)
```

How should I apply it correctly?

DRF extensions specifies for the decorator following requirenets for decorated method:

1) It should be method of class which is inherited from rest_framework.views.APIView

2) It should return rest_framework.response.Response instance.

taking into account point 1) I am not sure if its at all possible..

here is the source of drf `@api_view` decorator https://github.com/tomchristie/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/decorators.py

and here is the source of drf extension `@cache_response` decorator https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/blob/master/rest_framework_extensions/cache/decorators.py

Comment: Have you tried switching the decorators?

Comment: yes. still same error.

Comment: What does your [URLConf](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/http/urls/) look like?

Comment: I think urls have nothing to do here..

Comment: Well if it works when removing the `cache_response` decorator, indeed urls are not the issue.

Answer (score 8):

As **Ashish** mentioned `cache_response` decorator of drf-extensions is used for methods of `APIView` classes. But I wouldn't recommend it even in that case. Because Django already has support for using function decorators for methods.

So there are two way:

1 - Use **Django function views** with Django Rest Framework `api_view` decorator and Django `cache_page` decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from rest_framework.decorators import api_view


@cache_page(60 * 15)
@api_view(['GET', 'POST'])
def snippet_list(request):
    ...
```

2 - Use **Django Rest Framework class based views** with Django `method_decorator` decorator.

```
from django.views.decorators.cache import cache_page
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(cache_page(60 * 15), name='dispatch')
class SnippetListView(APIView):
    ...
```

The same is true about `never_cache`, etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can't use drf-extension's cache_response() for function-based-views. Check this [issue](https://github.com/chibisov/drf-extensions/issues/102)